# Upload file using webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have tried to upload a photo using the code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\path\\ben.jpg");
```

But the image is not getting uploaded.

The html of the upload button is

```
<button id="upfile1" class="buttonclass" style="cursor: pointer" type="button"> Choose Photo</button>
```

Is there any other way to upload image. I have tried using WebElement also. I need a solution in JAVA.

Comment: When you click a button, you will see a pop up box where you need to enter the image path. Click on the button and use Windows send keys to the pop up box.

Comment: ya when we click on that a pop up appears but its a different window right so how to sendkeys to that window/pop up? can u plz explain?

Comment: Is there any <input> element present on the page to upload the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upfile1")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\logo1.jpg");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

But is there any other simple methods to achieve the same other than using robot?

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Windows.Forms reference and try the below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("upfile1")).Click();
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("C:\\Users\\path\\ben.jpg");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: This shows an error in eclipse as System.Windows cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: The above code should work with C#. There might be other solutions in Java then.

Comment: Did you try Action class something like... 
`new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(ie).SendKeys("").Perform();`

Comment: I have tried using submit() but it is also not uploading the image.

Comment: Submit() can't be used for this kind, it is for Form submission only.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up which appears is a windows one.It should be handled using AutoIT.

Comment: But I am trying to automate the process with selenium.

Comment: @Dinu - Yes but you can integrate AutoIT code in the selenium code or you can download and add the AutoIT jar in your libraries and use the AutoIT code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RemoteWebDriver`, then you need to use `LocalFileDector` to upload the file to the remote selenium server first. And then use the remote path to upload from the remote selenium server.

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\path\\ben.jpg");
```